# How to add parameters when using HttpClient to send request .Net Core C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, httprequest, httpclient

How to add parameters when using HttpClient to send request?

I have a problem with my target API; it takes two parameters, and I need to figure out how to add two parameters to my request. Would anyone please explain how I can make that call with HttpClient?

My target API's signature, which I am going to call, looks like:

```
//It takes post call only
public string Authentication(string UN, string AP)
```

This is in my startup.cs:

```
services.AddHttpClient("Authentication", APIHttpClient =>
{
    APIHttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("Target API address");
}).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    new HttpClientHandler
    {
        UseCookies = false
    }
);
```

in my class:

```
public class MyService 
{
   private IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

   public MyService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory){
       _clientFactory = httpClientFactory;
   }

   public MyMethod(){

       HttpClient httpClient 
       _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Authentication");
       
       // I need to add parameter here
   }
}
```

Hopefully, someone can show me how to code it, Thank you!

Comment: "while httpclient has that option", could you share some code how do you add this option using httpclient?

Comment: The HttpClientFactory is used to create instances of HttpClient, not to send requests.

Comment: Also: what kind of parameters? Query? Body? Is it a GET? Is it a POST? Or something else?

Comment: Maybe consider a helper abstraction that implements best practices for you, like Refit? (Just to name _one_. Not affiliated to the project.)

Comment: @Fildor I showed the target API signature, it takes a Post call.

Comment: @QiangFu Took that back, I do not know how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send request with parameters like below if the api is POST request:

```
HttpClient httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient("Authentication");

// Create parameters
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "UN", "aa" },
    { "AP", "bbb" }
};

// Convert parameters to form-urlencoded content
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

// Send POST request
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("/auth", content);
```

The API:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/auth")]
public string Authentication([FromForm]string UN, [FromForm]string AP)
{
    return UN;
}
```

If the api is GET request:

```
HttpClient httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient("Authentication");

// Create query string with parameters
var queryString = new StringBuilder();
queryString.Append("?UN=").Append(Uri.EscapeDataString("aa"));
queryString.Append("&AP=").Append(Uri.EscapeDataString("bb"));

// Append query string to base URL
string requestUrl = "/auth" + queryString;

// Send GET request
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
```

Comment: OMG, thank you so much Rena! Those code look wonderful!